# Apple Pay using Stripe send token to server and charge for purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, stripe-payments, applepay

I am using `Apple Pay` in my iPhone application with payment Provider `Stripe`.

I implemented Apple Pay using test_key and it returns token and getting `PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusSuccess` in simulator.

Actually, I don't know the real time payment when it will done from the real device.

> I have a **question** is Do I need to send `Token` to server to charge
>   for that payment or will charge itself withing iPhone application once
>   get token?

As per below method they are sending token to server so It will charge only on server?

```
- (void)createBackendChargeWithToken:(STPToken *)token
                      completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus))completion {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com/token"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
NSString *body     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stripeToken=%@", token.tokenId];
request.HTTPBody   = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task =
[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
           completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                               NSURLResponse *response,
                               NSError *error) {
               if (error)
               {
                   completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusFailure);
                   ;
               }
               else
               {
                   completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusSuccess);
               }
           }];
[task resume];
}
```

Please suggest do we charge only from server?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to send the token to your server.

Creating a charge requires your secret API key which should never be accessible from your iPhone app.